# Projectiles only move if i hold the fire key down

Tags: python, pygame

Previously in my projectiles module, I had a class that handled each direction of fire seperately (a class for firing up, down, left and right) and this did it's job. However, now that I'm trying to incorporate shot speed and other things into the class, having 4 seperate classes is just too messy and so I tried to trim it down so that I only have one class for all projectiles fired.

However, now that I have done this, when I fire a projectile, it will only move so long as I am holding the fire button ('a' key if firing left) down. Also, if I fire left, then fire right, the projectile that was previously travelling left will begin to travel right instead.

My question is; How do I handle the projectiles so that when I fire one, it no longer accepts updates and travels in a straight line?

This is my working code;

## Main game module

```
import pygame
from constants import *
from player import Player
from Projectile import Projectiles

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])

pygame.display.set_caption('Labyrinth')

# Spawn player

player = Player(50, 50)
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(player)

projectile_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

done = False


# ----- Event Loop

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == ord('a'):
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == ord('d'):
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == ord('w'):
                player.changespeed(0, -3)
            elif event.key == ord('s'):
                player.changespeed(0, 3)

            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                projectile = Projectiles(0, 0)
                projectile.rect.x = player.rect.x
                projectile.rect.y = player.rect.y
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                projectile = Projectiles(0, 0)
                projectile.rect.x = player.rect.x
                projectile.rect.y = player.rect.y
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                projectile = Projectiles(0, 0)
                projectile.rect.x = player.rect.x
                projectile.rect.y = player.rect.y
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                projectile = Projectiles(0, 0)
                projectile.rect.x = player.rect.x
                projectile.rect.y = player.rect.y

            try:
                if projectile:
                    projectile_list.add(projectile)

            except:
                pass

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == ord('a'):
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == ord('d'):
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == ord('w'):
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
            elif event.key == ord('s'):
                player.changespeed(0, -3)


# ----- Game Logic

    all_sprites_list.update()
    projectile_list.update()



    screen.fill(GREEN)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    projectile_list.draw(screen)


    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

## Player module

```
from constants import *
import pygame
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    def __init__(self, x, y):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
```

## Projectile module

```
import pygame
from constants import *

class Projectiles(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 4])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()



    def update(self):

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.y -= 5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.y += 5
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= 5
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += 5
```

As always any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you only create ONE projectile. Your class is called `Projectiles` which is misleading because it's only one object not multiple.  This causes the projectile to be controlled even after firing.

Also, the reason why the projectile only moves while you press a key is that in the `update()` method, you only add to the projectiles x or y coordinate when e.g. `key[pygame.K_UP]:`  is true.

So, to fix this issues you will have to change the way your game handles projectiles.
If I understand your question right, you want to have multiple projectiles at once.
The way to implement this is to use a collection of projectiles.

**Game**

```
            //nothing changed till here

           elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                p = Projectile(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, -5, 0)
                projectile_list.add(p)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                p = Projectile(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, 5, 0)
                projectile_list.add(p)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                p = Projectile(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, 0, -5)
                projectile_list.add(p))
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                p = Projectile(player.rect.x, player.rect.y, 0, 5)
                projectile_list.add(p)

           // moved the part where you append the projectile to in the if statement

# ----- Game Logic

    all_sprites_list.update()
    projectile_list.update()

    screen.fill(GREEN)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    projectile_list.draw(screen)


    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

**Projectile:**

```
import pygame
from constants import *
// projectile needs to extend Sprite
class Projectile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, x_speed, y_speed):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 4])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.x_speed = x_speed
        self.y_speed = y_speed


    def update(self):

        self.rect.x += self.x_speed
        self.rect.y += self.y_speed
```

Im not so familiar with Pygame but I hope this will help you at least somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It certainly makes sense to do it this way!

Answer (score -2):

I have never used PyGame but one can see that your `update()` method in the `Projectiles` class depends on key press while it should depend on elapsed time instead.

Your projectile moves 5 units per key press, not 5 units per game tick once launched.

Comment: Oh okay, I'm also new to PyGame and coding in general; I only started a couple of weeks ago! I'm not quite sure how to change the `update()` to depend on elapsed time like you suggested. An example of what you mean in code format would be greatly appreciated!